# Unable to installed global npm package solc

Tags: solc, npm, solcjs

So, recently I got into security and started using Slither. I can run it on an entire project but not on a single file. According to my diagnose, the solc version is not compatible with my contract's declared version. And I found this amazing tool called solc-select which will be handy to audit contracts. However, my previously installed npm package (globally) is overriding it and I can't figure out how to uninstall it.

Comment: Probably this is unrelated to Ethereum. If it was installed with npm, try removing with `npm uinstall -g solc`. If it was installed in ubuntu using apt-get try removing the package. If that fails check where it is installed with `whereis solc` from the commandline, then try removing from the folder or changing its name. If all else fails you might to check with a forum specific to your OS to help removing an application.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's ethereum specific. I have tried `npm uninstall -g solc` multiple times without any success. I am pretty sure I used npm but I am checking apt and snap just in case. I might just uninstall npm, node and all global npm packages to be assured.

Comment: I'd suggest install node using a version manager like https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm, so you don't break the global installation.